# How to get all products info from database by SQL Query in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, php, sql, magento2.3.3, custom-reports

I want to get the below data of all products by SQL Query.

- SKU
- Product name
- Website
- Attribute set
- Quantity per source
- Sellable quantity
- visibility
- Price
- Status

> I have used this extension:
> https://github.com/degdigital/magento2-customreports
>  This
> extension has functionality to get the CSV report by SQL query. So I want to
> get product reports by SQL Query.

**Any Help much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggest for you that. First check these table on database you can find the query for all product .

tables are :

`catalog_product_entity` for sku, `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for name , `eav_attribute_set` for attribute set, `store_website` for website ,`cataloginventory_stock_item` for quantity and `catalog_product_entity_decimal` for price .

Comment: Thanks for it..But I want a SQL query for this. I tried to create this but not getting success. Also, "Quantity per Source" and "Sellable Quantity" also look like challenging points for me.

Answer (score 0):

The title can be different from one store view to an other. Same goes for the description. Also, some store views can use the default values set in the backend.

Here is a full query on how to get the data you need (sku, name, description) for all the products for a specific store view (id 1).

```
SELECT 

    `e`.`sku`, 
    IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`,
    IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description`


FROM 
   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` 
               ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` 
               ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` 
               ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` 
               ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)
```

If you want it for an other store view, just replace the value 1 with your desired id at the following lines

(`at_name`.`store_id` = 1)
and
(`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)

I don't know why you need this in an sql format. This is a strange and a big error source. You can easily get it through code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'description'));
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $name = $item->getName();
    $description = $item->getDescription(); 
    //do something with $sku, $name & $description
}
```

Comment: Can you add query for order list by sql

Comment: @LitExtension Thanks for it. Can you also please tell me how to get "Quantity per Source" and "Sellable Quantity"?

Comment: I don't know why you need this query in sql format. This is NOT ULTIMATE and it is not recommended during magento development. Magento already supports query functions, you can use it instead of these sql commands.
In your case, you can refer at: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-all-order-collection-filters-magento-2.html